# Prevent update prompt

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, ota-update

Is there a way *without* rooting to prevent galaxy nexus devices from prompting that there is an update available. We have several devices at work that we would like to keep on a particular android version for development reasons and it is somewhat of an annoyance being informed  repeatedly of the same update.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for FOTAKill.apk, it kills the Firmware Over The Air (FOTA). 
"Prevents GoogleServicesFramework from downloading OTA updates"

It's a fairly standard apk used and provided with some gapps packages (google apps package, when you install a custom ROM you don't get the google apps, need to install a gapps package)..
It works for both stock and rooted ROMS

The XDA forums have more information about it and download links of the apk, it originated from the CM ROM (cyanogenmod) but works on stock as well as custom ROMs.

Source code:
https://github.com/zinx/FOTAKill

Download etc for example from here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1832496

Comment: Can you give more information on just the name of the apk, how do you use it?

Comment: Fair enough, updated the answer

Comment: I would have upvoted, but clearly FOTAKill is based on CM, we do not know exactly if the OP is using a stock ROM or custom ROM... but being a Google Nexus  handset, it is probably stock ROM, based on the tag that the OP included in their question... and also, the github source is referring to Froyo, API 8 (look at the `AndroidManifest.xml`) that's CM/Froyo specific and not stock, plus its two years old and has not been updated since... :)

Comment: Your analysis is off, it is not *based* on CM, it *originated* from the CM project and works just fine on stock and custom ROMs. It works by preventing the "GoogleServicesFramework from downloading OTA updates" as stated in the answer, not anything custom made in the android system. Here is a link of people using and recommedning this on both stock and rooted ROMs recently. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1832496

Comment: Fair enough - when I stated "based on CM", I actually did meant its a CM thing, however, I stand corrected. Another solution, install droidwall if rooted and block off GoogleServicesFramework.... but then again that could prevent receiving any Google services such as sync and play store app updates :)